# Druid: using fields just for having/filter without output them

Tags: druid

I have a query that calculates per each user_id the last value and the max value, then does some calculation between them, and filter those rows in which the calculated value is bigger than 70.

The point is that the query returns back user_id, last, max, and the calculated field, **and I want just the user_id**, how can I achieve this?

I want this to achieve better performance since this query can return handers of thousands of records.

my query:

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource": {
    "type": "table",
    "name": "my-datasource"
  },
  "intervals": {
    "type": "intervals",
    "intervals": [
      "${startDate}/${endDate}"
    ]
  },
  "virtualColumns": [],
  "filter": {
    "type": "bound",
    "dimension": "sum_coins",
    "lower": "0",
    "upper": null,
    "lowerStrict": true,
    "upperStrict": false,
    "extractionFn": null,
    "ordering": {
      "type": "numeric"
    }
  },
  "granularity": {
    "type": "all"
  },
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "dimension": "user_id",
      "outputName": "d0",
      "outputType": "STRING"
    }
  ],
  "aggregations": [
    {
      "type": "doubleLast",
      "name": "last_coins",
      "fieldName": "sum_coins",
      "expression": null
    },
    {
      "type": "doubleMax",
      "name": "max_sum_coins",
      "fieldName": "sum_coins",
      "expression": null
    }
  ],
  "postAggregations": [
    {
      "type": "expression",
      "name": "drop_percentage",
      "expression": "(100-(\"last_coins\" / \"max_sum_coins\"*100))",
      "ordering": null
    }],
  "having": {
    "type": "filter",
    "filter": {
      "type": "bound",
      "dimension": "drop_percentage",
      "lower": "70",
      "upper": null,
      "lowerStrict": true,
      "upperStrict": false,
      "extractionFn": null,
      "ordering": {
        "type": "numeric"
      }
    },
    "finalize": true
  },
  "limitSpec": {
    "type": "NoopLimitSpec"
  },
  "context": {
    "sqlQueryId": "34ab9e888"
  },
  "descending": false
}
```